# Any way for Unix to ignore lpoptions and let Java do it's job?

Tags: linux, debian, printing, java, cups

I'm using the javax.print API to print a Jasper Report on Debian Linux. For some reason the saved lpoptions (CUPS settings) always override settings chosen on the Java Print dialog. At this point the only way I am getting around this problem is to delete the .lpoptions file in the user's directory.

This doesn't appear like something I can control with Java so is there a way to keep the Unix CUPS settings from overriding the print settings?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about Unix or Linux within the scope defined in the [help center](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).